# Signal Stack

Tags: c, signals

I did read that signals need to have a separate stack, why and how do you think it is implemented ?

Are they dynamically allocated or statically allocated ? How is memory allocation done ? Is it the same for all signals ?

Answer (score 4):

The reason that signals need a separate stack is that, if the normal stack gets corrupted or overflows, the signal can still execute. I think the signal stack is usually allocated dynamically, but it could implemented be either way. You can set a new signal stack with `sigaltstack`. It is the same for all signals.

Comment: So as I understand we have all default handlers onto the separate signal stack, is it true ?
What happens when we decide to use a different signal handler ? How is this special case taken care of ?

Comment: Non-default signal handlers are also executed on the same signal stack.

Comment: How could that be possible ? Non-default signal handlers would not be executed onto the same signal stack. Non-default signal handlers would be defined in the user program and would be using the normal user stack and not the special signal stack. I think we pass the pointer to the non-default signal handler which is later on used with the BSD signal API.

Comment: No, this is incorrect. Just because non-default signal handlers are defined in the user program doesn't mean that they have to execute on the user stack. I think you are not understanding how the stack actually works. Basically, the stack pointer is a register on the CPU, so if I change that register to another location, any functions I call will use stack space there. It doesn't matter where the function was defined.

Comment: Hi Zifre, I will appreciate if you can please answer this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761742/examinig-alternate-signal-stack-different-ways-to-allocate-it

Answer (score 2):

Another, more esoteric reason is to create user-level threads. See the paper, "Portable Multithreading" by Ralf Engelschall: http://www.gnu.org/software/pth/rse-pmt.ps. It describes how the "signal stack trampoline trick" is used to effect userspace threading.

Comment: Completely off-topic to this question (unfortunately), but very cool link :-)