# Do signal handers have a separate stack?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

Do signal handlers have a separate stack, (like each thread have separate stacks)?

This is in Linux/C context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Signal Stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841546/signal-stack)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Linux manual page [`signal(7)`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html):

```
By default, the signal handler is invoked on the normal process stack.
It is possible to arrange that the signal handler uses an alternate stack;
see sigaltstack(2) for a discussion of how to do this and when it might
be useful.
```